# Perl check internet connection for 30 seconds if stable, not stable and no internet connection

Tags: perl

I want script in perl that can check if my internet is stable, not stable or no internet connection.

I use Ping::Net script but reply is "You are connected to the internet.", not checking internet connection in 30 seconds if stable, not stable or no internet connection. Just reply "You are connected to the internet.". But the truth my internet connection is unstable. Every 3 seconds connect - disconnect.

This is the script

```
$ping = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
$ping->port_number("80");
if ( $ping->ping( 'www.google.com', '10' ) ) {
    print "You are connected to the internet.\n";
}
else {
    print "You are not connected to the internet.\n";
}
$ping->close();
```

I want to use wget as my tester, but I don't know how to script it in perl. My project is written on perl.

Comment: Please defined what you consider as stable, like: a specific site can be reached with ping, the site can be reached with HTTP, the reply is within a specific time .... Apart from that an ICMP ping cannot have any port number. Ports are only possible with TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your question properly, you mention you want to check with wget. I'm using LWP here to make the request in perl but you want to execute a program and get the result just use:

```
my $res = `wget -O - -q http://google.com`
```

But I'd suggest going for something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("007");

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://google.com');

my $res;
for (1..30) {
    $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ($res->is_success) {
        print localtime." Google is here\n";
    } else {
        print localtime."Google is gone\n";
    }
    sleep 1;
}
```

That won't check for exactly 30 seconds since the requests take time but I'm assuming that isn't really important

Comment: How about adding time limit?

Comment: I need this, can you add timeout, example this request will run in 10 seconds only.

Comment: I added a time limit right after I answered as I missed the "for 30 seconds" when first writing. The current code runs the loop 30 times and then exits, and sleeps 1 second between each. If you want to change to 10, change 30 to 10

Comment: @JeromeLaliag My pleasure. Regarding tweaks, you can edit LWP::UserAgent->new (timeout => 5); if you want a timeout on the request. As for die, sure switching print for die would work but if you want to see the flakiness it could make sense to have it printing since you'll see it going up and down. Hope your connection starts working properly :)